# PySerial in TkInter - How to time different in and outputs?

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, tkinter, pyserial

I have a serial port that receives one data point every second.

Now I would like to use a GUI with TkInter that contains a graph in matplotlib which plots the received data points in real time. At the same time I still
want to use the GUI to perform other basic things such as inputs and buttons for calculations with past data points etc.

I was wondering what would be the most efficient way to update the plot and at the same time listen to the serial port every second while still allowing the GUI and Python program to flawlessly work in the background.

I was thinking about using functions and call a getSerialData function every second from the mainloop but since I'm new to Python I don't really know how this structure works and if you guys could give me short outline how I should embed this into the main code.

Thanks!

EDIT #2: Ok, I got it to work. But it looks messy, is there maybe a better way to do this? I don't like all these different objects and self all the time, or is all of this necessary?

```
from tkinter import *
import serial


class SerialImport:

    def __init__(self, master): #master imports the root window

        self.printButton = Button(text="Test GUI response", command=self.printMessage)
        self.printButton.grid(row=0)

        self.openButton = Button(text="Open Serial Port", command=self.openPort)
        self.openButton.grid(row=1)

        self.closeButton = Button(text="Close Serial Port", command=self.closePort)
        self.closeButton.grid(row=2)

        self.updateButton = Button(text="Read and Print Data", command=self.update)
        self.updateButton.grid(row=3)

    def printMessage(self):
        print("GUI does respond!")

    def openPort(self):
        self.arduinoSerialData = serial.Serial('com3', 9600)

    def closePort(self):
        self.arduinoSerialData.close()

    def update(self):
        while(1==1):
            if (self.arduinoSerialData.inWaiting()>0):
                myData = self.arduinoSerialData.readline()
                self.temperature = float(myData)
                print(self.temperature)
                root.after(1000, self.update)
                break

root = Tk()
s = SerialImport(root) #root gets treated as master in SerialImport class
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: in `tkinter` you can use `root.after` to run some function every second. You can find many examples in answers on SO.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a good solution! I will try it later and give an update. Any idea how i could time the incoming serial data with this function. --- I mean if I call the function with root.after let's say every second. Then in the worst case the function needs to listen to the serial port for 0.9999 seconds to get the incoming data which would mean that the GUI is inactive for almost a second. Or is this not an accurate view how it works?

Comment: Need use threat on communication side. So create a `shared class` for accessing incoming data. One second not `realtime`, rtc required <60ms delay !